# Error with scikit-learn training: Unable to allocate array with shape

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have the following columns: Col1: string, Col2:float, Col3:float. During prediction I want to predict the value of `Col3`:

```py
import pickle
import numpy as np

from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

x_columns_to_encode = ['Col1']
x_columns_to_scale  = ['Col2']
y_columns_to_scale = ['Col3']

# Instantiate encoder/scaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
    
# Scale and Encode Separate Columns
x_scaled_columns = scaler.fit_transform(df1[x_columns_to_scale]) 
x_encoded_columns = ohe.fit_transform(df1[x_columns_to_encode])
y_scaled_columns = scaler.fit_transform(df1[y_columns_to_scale])
    
df = np.concatenate([x_scaled_columns, x_encoded_columns], axis=1)

validation_size = 0.50
seed = 7
x_train, x_validation, y_train, y_validation = model_selection.train_test_split(df, y_scaled_columns, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)
bestScore = 0.0
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()
score = model.fit(x_train, y_train).score(x_validation, y_validation)
print(score)
```

When I run this code I get error:

> "Unable to allocate array with shape (2763330, 25380) and data type float64"

Can someone please help me understand as to where am I making mistake?

Comment: on which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: This is likely due to the size of data you are passing to the model, do you need that many one-hot encoded values?

Comment: @thorntonc I have one onehot encoded column

Comment: One-hot encoding creates a binary column for each category of a categorical feature. You have thousands of values being encoded from `Col1` which creates a matrix too large for the model to fit on.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? In your code, df1 for instance is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One hot encoding generates a new column for every unique class in the categorical column. If your categorical column has too many unique classes, you can run out of memory.

It might help to show us what your data looks like, so we can provide better suggestions.

In the meantime, you could try the following options:

- Using a sparse representation for the one hot encoded matrix. This saves a lot of space, since a one hot encoded matrix has a lot of entries which are 0.
- Using a label encoding. However, be careful, because label encoding assumes an ordinal relationship between classes. It's better to use a tree-based model if there is no ordinal relationship between classes, as they don't use a mathematical equation to build the model, and so the ordinal relationship is not relevant when the decision tree makes the split.
  Refer [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/9447) for a clear explanation.
- Making a logical grouping of some of the classes. For example, suppose your categorical column has classes 'tiger', 'lion' and 'cheetah', you could group these together logically under a class, say, 'big_cats'. This will reduce the number of unique classes, and hence the number of new columns added will be less too.
- Drop the categorical column entirely.